# imagem de fundo não esta aparecendo no ionic viewe e nem no app compilado

Tags: css, ionic

Imagem de fundo não esta aparecendo no ionic viewe e nem no app compilado.

Quando eu coloquei para aparecer direto no hmtl desse jeito:

```
style="background-image:url(../img/santa-filomena3.jpg); background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;"
```

apareceu a imagem de fundo no browser, mas no ionic view e no app compilado não apareceu.

Alguém já teve esse problema?

Como não estava funcionando no browser criei ele no css, mas não consegui fazer funcionar ainda.

Style.css

```
.ion-content teste{
     background-image: url(.../img/fundo.jpg); 
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
}
```

principal.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
  <ion-content class="padding"  
               id="teste">

        <div class="row responsive-lg">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col" >
                  <span><a href="#/app/missa">Missa</a></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <span><a href="#/app/doacao">Doação</a></span>
                </div> 
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col" >
                  <span><a href="#/app/confissao">Confissão</a></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                 <span><a href="#/app/santaFilomena">Santa Filomena</a></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                 <span><a href="#/app/secretaria">Fale Conosco</a></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <span><a href="#/app/site">Site</a></span>
                </div> 
              </div>

        </div>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui arrumar ja.
css

```
.principal-custom {
     background-color: #FF4500;
     background-image: url(../img/fundo.jpg); 
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
}
```

principal.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
  <ion-content class="principal-custom">
          <div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col" >
                  <span><a href="#/app/missa">Missa</a></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <span><a href="#/app/doacao">Doação</a></span>
                </div> 
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col" >
                  <span><a href="#/app/confissao">Confissão</a></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                 <span><a href="#/app/santaFilomena">Santa Filomena</a></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                 <span><a href="#/app/secretaria">Fale Conosco</a></span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <span><a href="#/app/site">Site</a></span>
                </div> 
              </div>

        </div>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```